# How change Show Application key to Apple mouse?

Tags: 12.10

I want to change shortcut "show all application" (default super+w) to Apple mouse (click in one time left and right button). Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install a package called `ccsm` (CompizConfig Settings Manager).

```
sudo apt-get install ccsm
```

(or using Ubuntu Software Center, of course).

Please note that you should be careful. Compiz is not rock-stable, playing with its settings can result in compiz loosing all settings or shutting down. Ccsm is not recommended by Ubuntu. However, many people, including myself, think that it is a must-have tool necessary to adjust the system to ones needs.

Start ccsm (either type `ccsm` on the command line, or from Unity dash). In the text field on the left, type "scale" and select the "Scale plugin" on the right. Click on the "Bindings tab". This is what you should see:

[image]

The red arrow shows what you need to click to set up your mouse action to initiate window picker for all windows. If you want, in addition, to disable the keyboard shortcut, click on the backspace symbol next to the super-w shortcut.